# Delet multiple files with same name via SSH

Tags: ssh

I am currently in public_html dir and when  executing

rm  filename.php

it removes only that file in public_html dir ,

but in over 80 sub dirs I have and also need to remove the same file .

What would command be for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the fully qualified name of the directory, how about:

```
find /var/public_html -name "filename.php" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: which ever works , I just need to make sure folders stay intact and only the file in question is gone from all sub dirs

Comment: that's what that command does. Just replace **/var/public_html** with the actual directory name you want to recurse through.